# Meaning of 時間も時間だし?

Tags: time

I've seen this a couple of times and it seems to simply mean "it's about time, so ___", but why is that?

Comment: May not be the exact duplicate, but at least highly related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15039/5010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nuance**

> "時間も時間だし"
>   "(今の)時間も(___の)時間だし"

**Example**

> "時間も時間だし、家に帰ろう。"
>   "(今の)時間も(門限の)時間だし、家に帰ろう。"
>   "it's about time, so curfew. Let's go back home."
>   "Now Time is a time of curfew. Let's go back home." *<- Nuance*

I apologize if there are any mistakes in my English writing.