# The meaning of なだけに in this sentence

Tags: meaning

I am struggling with the meaning of this sentence:

> 「いい人そうな方ですが…**いい人なだけに**…ね」

(Context: Two students are walking down the hallway and are casually talking to each other, while a guard person or something mistakes them for making out and scolds them for that. After the guard introduces himself, one of the students says the sentence above.)

Consindering this: [Meaning of "だけに"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/54611/meaning-of-%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%ab)
 Could it mean: Because X is a good person, X is said to be a good person? (If X would not be a good person X would not be said to be a good person)

Comment: This link may be related, but I still can't work out the meaning: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/what-exactly-does-the-grammatical-form-n%e3%81%8cn%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%ab-mean

Comment: I initially put that link into my question as well, but I somehow got the feeling that it is not the same pattern here...

Comment: (To extent on the context: The reaction of the "guard" seemed to be way over the top and he says it is his work to keep the students' proper behavior) I think that the pattern linked in the question and explained in the video (in the original question) is more similar than the one in https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15039/what-exactly-does-the-grammatical-form-n%e3%81%8cn%e3%81%aa%e3%81%a0%e3%81%91%e3%81%ab-mean; however, the word order does not "quite fit" with this one as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this ～だけに means "exactly because ～", "～, and for that very reason", etc.

> いい人そうな方ですが…
>   He seems nice/honest/earnest, however...
>
> いい人なだけに…
>   it's such a person who...
>   exactly because he is an "honest" person...
>
> ね
>   you know (what I mean).

So instead of explicitly saying the last part of the sentence, this person said ね, which is working like "you know what I mean". The implied message completely depends on the context. From the provided context it should be something negative like "he ended up taking his job too seriously", "he is honest to a fault", or "he is too naive".

Comment: Where is the な coming from, given 人 is not a  形容動詞?

Comment: @Sam The latter half of [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/58025/5010) is related. だけ can take any attributive form, and な is the attributive form of the copula だ. In stiff speech いい人であるだけに is better.

Comment: Ah, I had seen posts talk about 'attributive な' before, good to finally know how/when it works. Thanks!